# How do you temporally interpolate a large RasterStack object to a higher periodicity (weekly to daily)

Tags: r, stack, raster

In R, I am trying to interpolate between stacks that were created a at weekly time interval, to a daily time interval. Interpolation method can be nearest neighbor or linear interpolation.

I have seen this can be done for time series using na.approx or a spline.

Also, I would like to keep the object as a Stack (no dataframe) if possible.

```
#Dummy example
#---#

library(raster) 

# Create date sequence 
idx <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2000/12/31"), by = "week") 

# Create raster stack and assign dates 
r <- raster(ncol=20, nrow=20) 
s <- stack(lapply(1:length(idx), function(x) setValues(r, 
runif(ncell(r))))) 
s <- setZ(s, idx) 

# Do interpolation to daily resolution
# (Perhaps it should be done one by one, perhaps all at once...)
# ...
```

Say my actual stack has dimensions c(20,20,52), the result would have dimensions c(20,20,366).

Thank for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a function `f`, that does this for a vector (a cell), say `s[1]`. Then apply this function using `calc`, as in `calc(s, f)`

Here is a simple example that uses `approx`, that can be replaced by spline or other interpolators

```
library(raster) 
r <- raster(ncol=20, nrow=20) 
s <- stack(lapply(1:length(idx), function(x) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r))))) 
idx <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2000/12/31"), by = "week") 
dr <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2000/12/31"), by = "day") 

f <- function(x) approx(idx, x, dr, rule=2)$y
# test <- f(s[1])

x <- calc(s, f)
```

Results for one cell

```
plot(dr, as.vector(x[1]), pch="+")
points(idx, as.vector(s[1]), pch=20, col="red", cex=2)
lines(idx, as.vector(s[1]), col="blue")
```